# How can I properly loop this multiplication?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the depreciation of an object over 20 years by 15% of its original value each year. The problem is it only subtracts the result of the first multiplication into the rest of the loop instead of decreasing the value by 15% 20 times.

```
ovalue = int(input("Enter the value of the car: "))
res = ovalue * 0.15
fvalue = ovalue - res
year = 1
while (year <= 20):
   print("Year ",year,":", fvalue)
   year = year+1
   fvalue = fvalue-res
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you so much

Comment: Please update your question with the output you require and the output you are seeing.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but if you take out 15% of the original value 20 times, isn't that like 300%?

Comment: Your code seems to *exactly* fit your requirement stated in your first sentence.

Comment: If you are really trying to do a depreciation calculation, I would argue that your first statement is wrong. The depreciation is usually calculated year over year, so it should simply be `ovalue* ((1-depreciation_rate)**n_years)`

Comment: If none of the answers is helpful to you it would be good if you comment, so that the answers can be improved. If you have answers that are the solution to your question, then choose one and accept it as answer ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work ) Accepting answers helps others to see what helped you (what was helpful to the question) Additionally you get +2 reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

This will decrease the value by 15% of current value on each iteration

```
value = int(input("Enter the value of the car: "))

year = 1
while year <= 20:
   value -= value * 0.15
   print("Year ",year,":", value)
   year = year+1
```

This will decrease the value by 15% of original value on each iteration (which is probably not what you want)

```
value = int(input("Enter the value of the car: "))

deduction = value * 0.15
year = 1
while year <= 20:
   value -= deduction
   print("Year ",year,":", value)
   year = year+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
price = []
for i in range(1,20):
    value -= value*0.15
    price.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have said, you want to multiply by the depreciation value. Note that if it depreciates 15%, it's new value will be 85% of its current value. Since this is multiplication we can use powers.

```py
def depreciate(initialValue, depreciationRate, numYears):
    depreciationRate = 1 - depreciationRate
    return initialValue * (depreciationRate ** numYears)
```